# Multiplying column values in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, calculation

I am currently making a payroll system and I am trying to make calculations between columns. I am trying to multiply a constant value to the values in a column named **PayRate**

I currently have two forms. the first form is where I tick off all necessary deductions and earnings. when this is accomplished, a button will be clicked and a second form containing the datagridview with the employee details and pay rate will be shown.

here is my code:

```
    Private Sub btnPayroll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPayroll.Click
    myConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;   Data Source = C:\Users\MatMat\Documents\PBIPayrollMgmt1.accdb;"
    myConnection.Open()

    datagridshow()

    Me.Hide()
    viewPayroll.Show()

    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
        Try
            Dim icell As Double
            Dim totalpay As Double

            icell = viewPayroll.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value

            totalpay = icell * 11.0

            viewPayroll.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value = totalpay


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

what it does what i need to but it only multiplies the value in the first row. How do I apply it to all rows? Is there such a thing as "CurrentColumn"?

Picture below for reference:

[2nd Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ConVy.png)

Comment: You need to learn about loops, which are one the most fundamental building blocks in any programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it only multiplies the value in the first row

Naturally. You are doing the calculations to only the `CurrentRow`:

Instead, you need to loop through all the rows in the `DatagridView` and apply the calculations, like so:

```
For Each rowX As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
    rowX.Cells(5).Value = rowX.Cells(5).Value * 11.0m;
Next
```

Also, you gonna need to place your loop in a more appropriate handler, such as [DataGridView.DataBindingComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: That is C# code. Question was in VB with no C# tag.

Comment: Thanks for the idea sir! Although this seems to be in C#, the idea of the loop is actually a stepping stone already. I will study this then. Thank you so much!

Comment: How do I change the "currentRow" selection for each loop iteration? i mean a formula perhaps? I tried using for but it doesn't move to the next row. Only the first row is being multiplied.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: Opps. That's my bad. I've changed it to VB.NET already. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @matmatpancakes: You change the selection by setting the `DataGridViewRow.Selected` property. But you don't need to in that particular case. Just apply the calculation to a cell's value within the `rowX` and that's it.

Comment: @BozhidarStoyneff i am sorry i didn't quite understand the code. Specifically "dgv.Rows" and "rowX" This is the first time i have seen these syntaxes.

Comment: @BozhidarStoyneff Ran my mouth before my mind. Sorry. I already figured it out. For others who need help, "dgv.Rows" wherein dgv is the namin of your datagridview and rowX.Cells[5] returns an error. it should be rowX.Cells(5). Thanks so much Bozhidar! God Speed!